# No system tray icon for Ibus in Elementary OS Juno

Tags: wingpanel, system, release-juno, ibus

I have install Ibus and Ibus-Unikey to type my native language in Elementary OS Juno. Everything works very well, except the case that there is no system tray icon for Ibus, just a band of three images like configuration things as in the photo: 
[image]

My question is, how to display Ibus properly in system tray? Please help me. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Knumber10

From your screenshot it would appear that you have a few extra icons in your wingpanel so this solution may be redundant.  However, let's give it a shot!

There is a site maintained by [mdh34](https://github.com/mdh34/elementary-indicators) that is the unofficial guide to restore indicator functionality on Elementary OS.

The **TLDR** boils down to this, if you want to install the prepackaged .deb packages then you would follow these steps:
1. Download the patched Ubuntu `indicator-application` package [here](https://github.com/mdh34/elementary-indicators/releases).
2. Download the latest `wingpanel-indicator-ayatana` package [here](https://launchpad.net/~elementary-os/+archive/ubuntu/stable/+files/wingpanel-indicator-ayatana_2.0.3+r27+pkg17~ubuntu0.4.1.1_amd64.deb).
3. To install the packages, you can use a .deb installer or enter the following command in *Applications -> Terminal* (or Win+T):
Type: `cd ~/Downloads`
Type: `sudo dpkg -i indicator-application-patched.deb`
Type: `sudo dpkg -i wingpanel-indicator-ayatana_2.0.3+r27+pkg17~ubuntu0.4.1.1_amd64.deb`
**NOTE:** The command above should be entered on **one** line only.
4. Once you've installed both packages, a reboot should get your indicators working in Pantheon.

What I like about mdh34's site is that he shows you the process of patching the files on your own.  That appeals to the security conscious side of my nature.  However, I understand that this is not for everyone.  If you are comfortable with the pre-patched files, go ahead and use them!

I hope that helps!  Good luck.

Comment: I have install indicatior-application and wingpanel-indicator-ayatana packages, and wingpanel works well with megasync, telegram, skype, but ibus still a problem. And also, after last update several days before, there is no indicator for megasync, dropbox, telegram, skype, etc as well. I really don't understand, what 's the problem with Juno's developer?